# How to query PostgreSQL for a list of schemata with comments?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get a list of schemata in PostgreSQL (9.6) along with any comments which might have been added...

**This works great to get a list of schema names:**

```
select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata
```

...but how do you get the associated comment (if there is one) as well?

- I've found loads of stuff to get database/table/column comments... schema comments seem to be evading me?

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pg_namespace`

```
select nspname as schemaname, 
       obj_description(oid, 'pg_namespace') as comment
from pg_namespace;
```

---

A good way to learn statements like that is to run `psql` with the `--echo-hidden` option and then use one of the meta commands to display the information.

If you e.g. run `\dn+` in psql you see:

```
postgres=> \dn+
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS "Owner",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(n.nspacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(n.oid, 'pg_namespace') AS "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1;
**************************

                           List of schemas
   Name    |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description
-----------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public    | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
           |          | =UC/postgres         |
 stuff     | postgres |                      |
 tablefunc | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+|
```

Comment: This is perfect... and thanks for the great tip @a_horse_with_no_name !